# Submit form values in JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm working on learning polymer.js. At the moment I'm just working on a simple web app to sign a user in. Currently, whenever I submit my form it submits in this format shown below versus a complete JSON object.

```
{
  email: "email@email.com",
  password: "password"
}
```

instead of ...

```html
{
  "email":"email@email.com",
  "password":"password"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post">

  <sign-in-input email="{{_email}}" password="{{_password}}"></sign-in-input>

  <input class = "paperbtn" type="submit" value="Sign in">

  <input name="email" value="[[_email]]" hidden>
  <input name="password" value="[[_password]]" hidden>

</form>
```

sign-in-input.html:

```
    <dom-module id="sign-in-input">
<template>
      <paper-input label = "Email" id = "email" required></paper-input>
      <paper-input label = "Password" id = "password" required></paper-input>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'sign-in-input',

    properties: {
      email: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      }
    },

    listeners: {
      'input': '_onInput'
    },

    _onInput: function() {
      this.email = this.$.email.value.trim();
      this.password = this.$.password.value.trim();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue. Are you talking about the space between the `:` and `"`? What does it matter?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I think the issue is `email: "email@email.com"` should be `"email": "email@email.com"` but it's not clear

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference, should it? What's the problem?

Comment: Strictly `email: "email@email.com"` is invalid json, try it in https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: "it submits in this format shown". Where are you seeing this? If it's in a browser console, you won't see it in "JSON" because the browser converts it automatically for display.

Comment: Why don't you send your POST request using an <iron-ajax> element? It JSON.strinfiy()-es the HTTP body automatically.

Comment: @Liam Sorry, for the confusion. Yes, the issue is email and password aren't in quotations so when I send my request to my handler I receive an error of "invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of object key string."

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Okay, thanks! I will try that!

Comment: @gforce301 Right now I'm seeing it because I'm using the http://httpbin.org/post to view how my form object looks when I submit my request. Currently, it's showing my object the way I mentioned instead of with the properties in quotations.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, it is making a difference. When I send an object without the properties in quotations I receive an error, however, when I send my object with the properties in quotes my request goes through successfully to my server via Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending an object (`obj`) when you should send a string.

Have you used `JSON.stringify(obj)` on the object that you want to send?

Other things that you're not asking about.

---

```
_onInput: function() {
  this.email = this.$.email.value.trim();
  this.password = this.$.password.value.trim();
}
```

You should use `this.set('email', this.$.email.value.trim()`because this.set sends an event in Polymer to update the value. This isn't an issue now, but it can be in other elements  if you continue to use `this.[property]`.

---

```
  <paper-input label = "Email" id = "email" required></paper-input>
  <paper-input label = "Password" id = "password" required></paper-input>
```

You can bind listeners to these right away, to avoid using:

```
listeners: {
  'input': '_onInput'
},

_onInput: function() {
  this.email = this.$.email.value.trim();
  this.password = this.$.password.value.trim();
}
```

It will look something like:

```
 <paper-input label="Email" id="email" value="{{email::input}}" required></paper-input>
 <paper-input label="Password" id="password" value="{{password::change}}" required></paper-input>
```

I used two kinds of Polymer listeners, input and change. You can use either.